# How can I find the Taylor series of a function using the known Taylor series of a related function?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

I am trying to calculate the Taylor series for the function:

$$f(x) = {\frac 1 x}(1 - \cos\sqrt{x})$$

How do I do it, if I know the Taylor series for $\cos(x)$?

$\cos x = {\Large \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}}\dfrac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$

It should be done just with algebraic modifications... Do I also need to know the Taylor series for $1/x$? Thank you!

Comment: The series for $\cos t$ is $1-t^2/2!+\cdots$. Plug in $\sqrt{x}$ everywhere for $t$. Subtract from $1$, divide term by term by $x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how come you comment an answer as opposed to posting the answer? I've seen that many places, and its clear you're very wise so I'm curious why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First plug in $x \to \sqrt{x}$ to get
$$
\cos(\sqrt{x}) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k (\sqrt{x})^{2k}}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{k}}{(2k)!}
$$

Now if you look at
$$
-\cos(\sqrt{x}) = -\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{k}}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^{k}}{(2k)!}
$$
Do you see how to proceed from here?

**EDIT:**

Notice then that the $k = 0$ term is $-1$ so that when we add $1$ to the sum this term cancels out so
$$
1-\cos(\sqrt{x}) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^{k}}{(2k)!}
$$

Finally we have
$$
\frac{1}{x} \left(1-\cos(\sqrt{x}) \right) = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^{k}}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^{k}}{x(2k)!} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^{k-1}}{(2k)!}
$$

Comment: These modifications I understand, but I am confused about this 1/x

Comment: @Sheppard simply multiply across the sum by $1/x$.

Comment: @Sheppard hopefully the edit helps

Comment: yes, this clarifies everything. It looks now a lot easier :-D. Much obliged!

Comment: @Sheppard no problem, glad to help!